# Anaconda and ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcgis-10.1, installation, numpy, anaconda, pandas

I am having problems installing Anaconda with ArcGIS 10.1. My problem is specifically with pandas. ArcGIS python is my default python version. I installed python 0.16.2 in this version, which installed numpy 1.9.2. Following some posts, I created a .pth file (with ZZ as preffix, in order to read first the default version modules) and put it in C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages, which points to the Anaconda packages (C:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages). I can import most of the Anaconda python modules, but I have a problem with pandas. When I import pandas, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version a but this version of numpy is 9
```

This only happens in a Windows command window, in ArcGIS python window imports the 0.16.2 version. The Anaconda pandas and numpy versions are 0.17.1 and 1.10.1. When I import the numpy version in a command window I get 1.9.2 (ArcGIS installed numpy version). The only problem is the error above with pandas, but after the error I check the version and says 1.9.2. I have read about creating environments in Anaconda, but I need the pandas 0.16.2 version because of some new funcionalities not present in older versions. I tried uninstalling the ArcGIS pandas version to use the Anaconda version, but I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas import hashtable, tslib, lib
  File "pandas\src\numpy.pxd", line 157, in init pandas.hashtable     (pandas\hashtable.c:38262)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

Does anyone how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I suspect that this question may be better researched/asked at [so] because the error that you have shown makes no mention of ArcPy or the Python installed by ArcGIS for Desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem installing numpy 1.10. It seems the Anaconda pandas version was compiled with numpy 1.10, and the numpy default python version was 1.9.